# I have two cols Street No and Street Name. when street name starts with hypen i dont want space between Street No & street Name while concatinating

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

ex : street No : 28
Street Name : -418 bangalore

Result : 28-418 Bangalore

StreetNo : 40
Street Name : Bangalore

result : 40 Bangalore

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve using IIF.
logic - if you see street name starts with dash, while concatenating, dont add a space, else add a space.

```
IIF( substr(Street_Name,1,1)='-', street_No||Street_Name, street_No|| ' ' ||Street_Name )
```